# Python raw_input() string as instance name

Tags: python, oop, instance

I'm working on a PhoneBook in python and I have a class from which I want the user to call instances via raw_input.

For example

```
class PhoneBook():

    def Add(self):
        print "Name added"

def main():
    pb = PhoneBook()
    Input = raw_input()
    #Here I want to call pb.add() (and in the future other alternatives)
    #using the string Input. As I want it (but I know doesn't work): pb.Input[0]
    #provided the user types Add
```

Is it possible to use the string to call pb.Add()?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(pb, Input)()
```

`getattr` returns the *function*, and doesn't call it. Hence the extra `()` at the end.

Some other things:

- You should *return* `"name added"` instead of printing it.
- Leave uppercased-named variables for classes :). Lowercase for functions, etc.

Comment: Yeah the print was just there for the sake of testing.
Ok, thanks for the help!

Comment: @ingen Thought so :p. No problem :D

Comment: Lets say I want to send parts of Input to the Add() function, since Add() is going to add names to the phonebook, how would I do that?

Comment: @ingen I'm not sure I understand you perfectly, but you can allow the functions to take specific arguments (or 'parameters', if you prefer)

Comment: Sorry, I'm just being tired now, I solved it. Of course I just have to add them in the parentheses...